# In MySQL, how would I model moves that Pokemon can learn?

Tags: data-structure, mysql

I'm making a Pokemon MMO Game with Unity + SmartFoxServer/MySQL. At the moment I'm creating the base structure for the database.

If you are not familiar with Pokemon Games, every Pokemon can learn only a fixed set of moves. I want to represent this in my database. **How should I do it?**

---

Currently I have a *pokemon_base* table that is storing all the base data of the Pokemon, like name, elemental types, base stats, etc, and a Unique Identifier. I need for every Pokemon inside this table to have a list of learnable moves.

I have these ideas to continue:

- Have a field on the Pokemon table containing comma-separated IDs of learnable moves
- Have a field on the Moves table containing comma-separated IDs of Pokemon that can learn this move, or
- Have another Table with a Field for Pokemon ID and boolean fields for each move

The first one to me seems the better because once I have a Pokemon ID I can get all the moves in a string, which I can split by commas and do my checks. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an intermediary table that maps Pokemon to learnable skills:

[image]

Now you can select all the learnables for a Pokemon by name:

```
SELECT LearnableSkills.ID FROM LearnableSkills, PokemonLearnables, Pokemon
WHERE LearnableSkills.ID = PokemonLearnables.LearnableID
AND PokemonLearnables.PokemonID = Pokemon.ID
AND Pokemon.Name = 'byte56'
```

Or by ID:

```
SELECT LearnableSkills.ID FROM LearnableSkills, PokemonLearnables
WHERE LearnableSkills.ID = PokemonLearnables.LearnableID
AND PokemonLearnables.PokemonID = 56
```

Comment: Naive question! Why don't you put LearnableID directly inside the Pokemon table?

Comment: Placing it in a separate table allows for multiple LearnableSkills IDs. If you place the LearnableID directly in the Pokemon table, you only get one LearnableSkills ID or you're required to do workarounds like using a comma separated list that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Ok I see. So if each Pokemon has only one Learnable skillset, would it be good practice to put LearnableID directly inside the Pokemon table?

Comment: Yes. That would work, if you have *skillsets*, this question was about learnable skills or moves, not sets.

Comment: Oh, missed that, sorry. Thanks for the additional answers!

Comment: Thanks, since i am not an expert of MySQL, this type of query is not intensive on the server? Because a similar query will be run lot of times (eg: teaching a move to a pokemon, trading, battles, etc)

Comment: This is a trivial query.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have time at the moment to create a visio diagram showing this in practice, but in within the Pokemon games the move sets have an elemental type that determines which Pokemon can learn those moves. As such, I don't know if it's best to keep a table listing all of the available moves each Pokemon can learn as answered above.

For instance, ThunderShock is an electric type move that electric type Pokemon can learn.

The elemental types include:

- Water
- Grass
- Fire
- Ice
- Electric
- Psychic
- Dragon
- Dark
- etc. (and more I believe)

Within your database, I'd suggest the following tables:

ElementalType (primary key ID, Name)

Pokemon (primary key ID/#, Name, foreign key ElementalType.id as TypeID)

Moves (primary key ID, Name, Damage, PowerPointsRequired, foreign key ElementalType.id as TypeID)

To store moves known, an association table
LearnedMoves (foreign key Pokemon.id as PokemonID, foreign key Moves.ID as MoveID)

Then to show the moves a Pokemon could learn, you could run the following query:

```
    SELECT * from Moves m
    INNER JOIN ElementalType t ON m.TypeID = t.ID 
    INNER JOIN Pokemon p ON p.TypeID = t.ID
    WHERE p.ID = @PokemonID
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that not every Pokemon can learn every move of its own type. Also Pokemon can learn moves that have different types than themselves and they can have more than one type.

Comment: I agree with the above comment, but at the end of the day, the question isn't asking "How did Pokemon do it", its asking " How should I do it". If you retail or this answer to be an example of how you *might* do it, instead of an inaccurate representation of how *Pokemon* does it, I will consider reversing my downvote